# VB.NET SqlConnection to MySQL Database

Tags: database, vb.net, mysql-connector

although I did read plenty of stackoverflow posts and also checked out lots of tutorial websites I can't get my code to work.

I want to use sqlBulkCopy. And therefor I need a instance of the 'SqlConnection' class. I have a MySQL Database running and I have no problem at all opening a connection with the 'MySqlConnection' class.

I have tried several approaches to get SqlConnection working.

MySqlConnection (works):

```
  Dim a = "Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=hauptdatenbank;User Id=johnny;Password=123456;"

  Using cn As New MySqlConnection(a)
     cn.Open()
  End Using
```

SqlConnection (does not work):

```
  Dim a = "Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=hauptdatenbank;User Id=johnny;Password=123456;"

  Using cn As New SqlConnection(a)
     cn.Open()
  End Using
```

Following SqlException gets thrown:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: I think you're mixing the database libraries. I would expect SqlConnection class to work only with a Microsoft SQL database.

Comment: That would explain a lot. Thanks already. So I do have no chance to use sqlBulk with a MySQL Database? If that extends this post, I can also open a new one.

Comment: Search 'sql bulk insert mysql vb.net' here or in google. There appear to be a few options available.

Comment: The MySQL Provider has its own bulk copy version

Comment: MySQL doesn't have an equivalent to SqlBulkCopy. The [MySqlBulkLoader](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html) class is a wrapper over `LOAD DATA INFILE`, the equivalent of `BULK INSERT` on SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SqlBulk is only for a SQL DB.
MySqlBulkLoader is for a MySQL DB.

Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Not only do MySQL and SQL Server use different providers, the bulk copy classes do a different job. MySQL's class just loads files from the server's local storage. It's a wrapper over the `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement, similar to executing `BULK INSERT` on SQL Server to load data from a local file

Answer (score -1):

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Module Connection

`Public str1 As String = "data source=localhost;user id= root;password=;database= parisbugdb;"`

End Module

```
If Len(Trim(PassBox.Text)) = 0 Then
    AlertLabel.Visible = True
    AlertLabel.Text = "Password required!"
    PassBox.SelectAll()
    PassBox.Focus()
    Return
End If

con.Open()
Dim Sql = "SELECT * FROM userx WHERE username ='" & UserBox.Text & "' AND password = '" & PassBox.Text & "'"
scmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
Dim sdr As MySqlDataReader = scmd.ExecuteReader


Try
    If sdr.Read = False Then

        AlertLabel.Visible = True
        AlertLabel.Text = "Login denied!"
        con.Close()
    Else

        UserBox.Clear()
        PassBox.Clear()
        UserBox.Focus()
        Me.Hide()
        Dashboard.Show()
    End If


Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString())
End Try
```

End Sub